# X Windows Server system on a console only based server

Tags: linux, console, server, x11

Newbie to stack overflow and am experimenting with running an X Server so my colleagues and I can access our Linux GUI applications from windows machines.

I know all about XMing and other utils but my question isn't on the MS Windows side, it's on the Linux host machine.  You see right now the linux boxes all have GUI's installed (CentOS and Ubuntu) with the configs to access via Xming or any other SSH X forwarding client.

My question is can I just setup the server to run the x system in the background without having to install a GUI?  Did some research and can't really figure it out as I'm not an X Windows guru.

Thanks for everyone's help.

cmillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have a full X server running or installed on the same system that is running X clients; only the libraries required for implementation of the protocol are required, and the system's package manager will handle installing those.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, not sure why this was off-topic as many of my google questions are answered by stack.  Perhpas is Stack Exchange versus Stack overflow.